# while loop not running until meeting completion condition

Tags: java, while-loop

I have created a while loop which can't seem to run properly. it calls a method from another class which helps change the stop condition for my program. It calls the method about 3 - 8 times on average and never reaches the stopping condition, however it stops.

```
    public class useExample
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {

       Example ex = new Example();
       long [] result;

       long a = 0;
       long b = 0;
       long c = 0;
       long d = 0;
       long e = 0;
       int count = 0;

       int a1 = 1;
       int b1 = 2;
       int c1 = 3;
       int d1 = 4;
       int e1 = 5;


      for(int i = 0; i <1; i++)
      {
        while(a != a1 && b != b1 && c != c1 && d != d1 && e != e1)
        {
          result = ex.getOnes();
          a = result[0];
          b = result[1];
          c = result[2];
          d = result[3];
          e = result[4];

          System.out.println(result[0] + " " + result[1] + " " + result[2] + " " + result[3] + " " + result[4]);

        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " " + count++);

        }
       System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " "+ count);

      }



     }
   }
```

The Example class is a follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Example 
{
  Random r = new Random();

    public long[] getOnes(){

        int a = r.nextInt(35);
        int b = r.nextInt(35);
        int c = r.nextInt(35);
        int d = r.nextInt(35);
        int e = r.nextInt(35);

        while(a == 0)
        {
            a = r.nextInt(35);
            //temp[0] = a;
        }

        while(b == 0 || b == a /*|| b == c || b == d || b == e*/)
        {
            b = r.nextInt(35);
            //temp[1] = b;
        }

        while(c == 0 || c == a || c == b /*|| c == d || c == e*/)
        {
            c = r.nextInt(35);
            //temp[2] = c;
        }

        while(d == 0 || d == a || d == b || d == c/*|| d == e*/)
        {
            d = r.nextInt(35);
            //temp[3] = d;
        }

        while(e == 0 || e == a || e == b || e == c|| e == d)
        {
            e = r.nextInt(35);
            //temp[4] = e;
        }

        return new long[] {a, b, c, d, e};
    }

}
```

The while loop of the useExample class should only stop when each condtion of the while is false.This means when:

```
a == a1
b == b1 
c == c1 
d == d1 
e == e1
```

It should output how many while loops it went through and the values of each loop. eventually outputting  the same values of a1 to e1.

Comment: *never reaches the stopping condition, however it stops* not at all clear what are expecting ?

Comment: This code doesn't compile, you have two variables with the name e in the same scope.  Please post valid code

Comment: At each call to `getOnes()`, there is one chance on  34*33*32*31*30 = (~33 millions) to have the right result. Did you wait enough?

Comment: I reached a count of 5 and then it stopped for it self as i was then able the enter the java run command again in the window.

Comment: Debug the code and find out.